# How to start powershelll and have it execute something right after?

Tags: command-line, powershell

Say I have in my profile `Microsoft.PowersShell_profile.ps1` (like `.bashrc`):

```
Import-Module posh-git
Import-Module oh-my-posh
Set-PoshPrompt -Theme half-life
```

but I don't want to execute it in regular powershell, only in Windows terminal's (WT) powershell (so I remove it from my profile).

In WT have the command `powershell.exe`; how can I have it execute something once launched, ie., inside ie., as if I typed the commands in the prompt ?

I could use `powershell.exe -Command "${ Import-Module posh-git; Import-Module oh-my-posh; Set-PoshPrompt -Theme half-life; }"` but is exits right after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to start powershelll and have it execute something right after?

You can improve your workflow as follows:

Create a custom profile file (PsProfilePoshGit.ps1):

```
Import-Module posh-git
Import-Module oh-my-posh;
Set-PoshPrompt -Theme half-life;
function global:prompt
{
    Write-Host -Object "Posh-Git" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Magenta
 
    return "> "
}
```

Within your Windows Terminal settings.json do something like as follows:

```
{
    "guid": "{01463d52-dda9-4109-b03f-c55899b52df2}",
    "name": "Powershell - Posh Git",
    "commandline": "powershell.exe -noprofile -noexit -command \"invoke-expression '. ''C:/PsProfilePoshGit.ps1''' \"",
    "hidden": false
}
```

Source: [Windows Terminal - Launch powershell with different profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62678818/windows-terminal-launch-powershell-with-different-profile)